# WrongValueClass in apache Mahout

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mahout

I have written a mapreduce programm using mahout.  the map output value is `ClusterWritable` .when i run the code in eclipse, it is run with no error, but when i run rhe jar file in terminal, it shows the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: wrong value class: org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable is not class org.apache.mahout.clustering.iterator.ClusterWritable
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:988)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.canopy.CanopyMapper.cleanup(CanopyMapper.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:621)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)
```

The output code in map is:

```
context.write(new Text(), new ClusterWritable());
```

but i don't know why it says that the value type is `VectorWritable`.

Answer (score 0):

Mapper being run, resulting in stacktrace above is Mahout's CanopyMapper, and not custom one you've written.
CanopyMapper.cleanup method is outputting (key: Text, value: VectorWritable).
See [CanopyMapper.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/canopy/CanopyMapper.java)

See also [CanopyDriver.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/canopy/CanopyDriver.java) and its buildClustersMR method, where MR job is configured, mapper, reducer, and appropriate output key/value classes.

You didn't state, so I'm guessing that you're using more than one MR job in a data flow pipeline. Check that outputs of each job in pipeline are valid/expected input for next job in pipeline. Consider using cascading/scalding to define your data flow (see http://www.slideshare.net/melrief/scalding-programming-model-for-hadoop)

Consider using [Mahout user mailing list](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/Mailing+Lists,+IRC+and+Archives) to post Mahout related questions.

Comment: Slavic: I have added mahout 8 jar files into the lib folder of project.The output value in mahout 8 is ClusterWritable.